# how can i read one memory byte

Tags: c++, memory, byte, memcpy

Here is memory block I'm working with:

[image]

You can see `8b ff 55 8b ec 83 7d 0c 01 . . . .` code. I want to get one each byte, so I tried:

```
DWORD offset; // this memroy has '0x61CAB0E4' and that means '8b ff 55... memroy block'
BYTE Result;
memcpy(&Result, &offset, 1); //1 mean byte as I want
```

BUT, the result is not correct. If I debug, the result value is `228` and I was expecting that value would be `8b`.

How can I memory block one byte one?

```
8b,
ff,
55,
8b,
ec,
83,
7d,
```

....etc

These are the results:

[image]

Comment: Are you using C? You should tag the appropriate language.

Comment: `memcopy` does copy ` bye exactly, I'm not sure what your problem is? How are you trying to look at `Result`?

Comment: i debug result value by using visual studio 'watch'

Comment: i attach debugging picture

Comment: my problem is i want to get '8b' but i can't

Comment: after that i wil compare

Comment: if(result == 139) //139 = 8b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not converting properly your result, and misinterpreting:

1. Your result is indeed decimal - 228.
2. In binary this is `11100100`
3. The data is most likely stored in 2s complement in your P and depending on the endian and assuming the debugger just interpreted the binary as binary you get `10001011` - this is 139.
4. Finally, convert to two digit hex number: `1000` is 8, `1011` is `11` which is `b`, so finally `8b`.

Comment: after that offset += 1 (1byte move)

Comment: and memcpy same thing

Comment: but that result is 229.

Comment: but 229 is not same ff as i thought

Comment: If you did not move the offset yourself, it won't move - you're probably copying the same thing.

Comment: but as all my code, i add offset move, by using offset += 1;

Comment: you can see picture "attach result picture"

Comment: Please print it (cout) and to the terminal to make sure what you're seeing.

Comment: sorry.. i cant understand what you mean... so sorry;

Comment: I realized that I needed to use a pointer to transfer my address.

Comment: But with C ++ code, i dont know how to convert it into regular binary. for example 228 to 139

Comment: i dont understand how to change 228 to 139.

Comment: if 11100100(228) is stored in little-endian as 2s complement

Comment: 11100100 -> 00100111(little-endian)

Comment: you say 2s complement, so 00100111 -> 11011000 -> 11011001